# src vs srctarget vs srcwait

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I continue to work on a project that I do not fully understand yet. I encountered the following line of code:

```
<iframe id="AddDialog" style ="overflow: hidden; width:1150px; height:450px;" class="Dialogframe"  scrolling="no"  srcwait=@Html.Raw("'" + Url.Action("Index", "FieldChooser") + "'") srctarget=@Html.Raw("\"" + Url.Action("Index", "FieldChooser", new { ColumnFormat = false, resultmodel = Guid.Empty, datatype = "", multiselect=false }) + "\"") src=@Html.Raw("\"" + Url.Action("Loading", "FieldChooser") + "\"")></iframe>
```

Visual Studio tells me that srcwait and srctarget are not valid HTML5-elements, but it seems to work. The Loading View is shown for a few seconds and then the Index() method is executed (the one called in srctarget).

I am also not able to find anything on the internet about the attributes srctarget and srcwait. So what are the differences between src, srctarget and srcwait? Do they even exist or is that some invention of the person that worked on it before me?

I have a function in the FieldChooserController

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
     ...
    }
```

I want this to be called when I click on the OK button. I assumed that the srcwait part is meant for that because the call looks like that, but the function is never called.

Please bear with me and tell me if you need to see more code, at this point I have no idea what is important.

```
            buttons: {
                OK: function() {
                //Save selected Value

                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    if (GlobalName !=''){
                         addwhere(GlobalName,opts.sourceel,GlobalDefVal,GlobalDataType,GlobalValue);
                         }
                              $('#AddDialog').attr('src', $('#AddDialog').attr('srcwait'));
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                              $('#AddDialog').attr('src', $('#AddDialog').attr('srcwait'));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There most probably is a piece of JavaScript running, which sets the `src` to `srcwait` when an operation is performed where the user will be waiting for a wile, for example to show a loading screen.

As for your code, if you have a `HttpPost` annotated `Index()` method you wish to call upon a button click, you must create a form and let it post there:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "FieldChooser", FormMethod.Post)
{
    <input value="OK" type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: great, thanks to your hint I found the javascript! so far I haven't looked to deeply into the javascript of my project. I added the piece which I think is doing the job to my post. Maybe the index() method is not supposed to be used after all, and everything else is done in the javascript method addwhere() ... does that make sense?

Comment: @Expecto that's a bit hard to answer, as I don't know what you're trying to do or what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: I want to add some things to the View that contains the iframe after the user clicks OK. I guess it would be OK to do it with javascript or with the POST-method (I'd prefer C#) but my predecessor seems to have started doing it in javascript. Since it's not a very complicated task it is probably more useful anyway (and I just have to overcome my aversion to javascript).